# In Windows 7 you can drag a window to each side to split to 2 screens, can you get 4 with multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

As the question states... In Windows 7 with a single screen, you can drag a window to the right and a window to the left to maximize them both at half the screen, letting you quickly and neatly see two windows simultaneously.

If I have 2 monitors, is there a way to do this with 4 windows, where each monitor gets 2 windows split across each screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not by only using the mouse, but you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to dock a window to the left or right side of a screen. Doing so will allow you to have 4 windows which all span half of a screen.

As a side note, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> move a window between screens.

Comment: *> Not by only using the mouse* Really? Aero Snap dragging does not work for multiple monitors? That’s kind of surprising, especially if the keys *do* work. `:-|` Maybe they’ll fix that in a future update.

Comment: That's amazing, I never could figure that out. I guess I didn't try very hard, just went with a multiple monitor manager. +1

Comment: @Synetech I was looking into this problem myself shortly after Windows 7 was released. I would be very surprised to learn that it can be done by mouse alone.